# Operator= of class 'Entity' doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, entity

Okay so I'm making my own Entity Component System, and I want to be able to set an Entity to another, here is how it looks:

```
Entity& operator=(const Entity& other) {
    this->Name = other.Name;
    this->Tag = other.Tag;
    this->IsStatic = other.IsStatic;
    return Entity(this->Name, this->Tag, true, this->IsStatic);
}
```

an Entity also has an ID which has to be unique from other Entities, but when i set an Entity to another, the ID also gets set:

```
'main.cpp'

Entity a = Entity("a", "tag of a"); // A automatically gets ID: 0 because its the first Entity created
Entity b = Entity("b", "tag of b"); // B gets ID: 1 because its the second Entity created
a.PrintAll(); // This is a function which prints the name, tag, and ID of an Entity, this prints out: " "a" has "tag of a" as a tag, and its ID = "0" "
// but after i set a to b, things get a little messy
a = b;
a.PrintAll(); // This now prints out: " "b" has "tag of b" as a tag, and its ID = "1" ", that should not happen, why did the ID of a change ?
```

the way IDs work is that when an Entity is constructed its ID is set to a global variable which increments by 1, like so:

```
'Public.h' // this is included everywhere, has all the global variables

int IDcounter = 0;
int GetNewID(){
 return IDcounter;
 IDcounter++;
}
```

And then inside the Entity constructor:

```
'Entity.cpp'

Entity::Entity(string name, string tag){
 this->name = name;
 this->tag = tag;
 this->ID = GetNewID(); // Everything fine, the problem is the operator=
}
```

EDIT:

I tried what you guys told me, here is how i tried it:

```
Entity* leshko;
Entity* ent2;
leshko = new Entity("leshko", "lesh"); 
ent2 = new Entity("ent2", "presh");
leshko->PrintAll(); // ID = 0
leshko = ent2;
leshko->PrintAll(); // ID = 1
```

I think the problem may be that I'm using pointer 'Entities' and not regular 'Entities', but I cannot change that.

Comment: Recommend a read of [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for what is often a better way to do `operator=`.

Comment: _"I tried what you guys told me, here is how i tried it:"_ Who told you to do that? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok i'm pretty sure users: NathanOliver and Sam Varshavchik suggested that i use 'return *this', if i'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: At no point did they instruct you to rewrite your code to use dynamic allocation everywhere. And there is no `return *this` in your "here is how i tried it" modified code snippet.

Comment: _"I think the problem may be that I'm using pointer 'Entities' and not regular 'Entities', but I cannot change that."_ No, you weren't using pointer 'Entities' (but now you are). I'm very confused by this question, and so are you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you are trying to return a reference to a local variable.  In your assignment operator you have

```
return Entity(this->Name, this->Tag, true, this->IsStatic);
```

Which creates a temporary.  You cannot return that by reference.

What you want to do instead is return a reference to the object you just assigned to.  You do that with

```
return *this;
```

---

Note that in your code `leshko = ent2;` is pointer assignment not object assignment.  If you want to assign the underlying objects you need `*leshko = *ent2;`.

Comment: It worked, I did some tests using integers and knew It was pointer assignment but didnt know how to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator=` needs to simply return `this`.

```
Entity& operator=(const Entity& other) {
    this->Name = other.Name;
    this->Tag = other.Tag;
    this->IsStatic = other.IsStatic;
    return *this;
}
```

After all, `*this` is what you've just assigned to, and that's the result of the `=` operator, a reference to `*this`.

Comment: Yes that was how i had it the first time, then i changed it to the one shown up there, it doesn't work.